# Can I use AngularJS with Static Google Maps?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-static-api

> "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=440x420&scale=2&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off&markers=color:green|size:small|90,-180"

So I have something like the link shown above. That link doesn't quite work, all I did was shorten it down to 1 coordinate and using a possibly not correct coordinate.

BUT, you should get the idea. Should I be able to instead do something like this:

```
<div id="mapWrap" ng-controller="EdwardMap">
  <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=440x420&scale=2&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off&markers=color:green|size:small|{{building.mapcoord}}" usemap="#Map">
```

I have attempted it and I cannot get it to work. I have other code below it that uses the same controller and is working fine, but I was hoping that Angular could help me generate the image! And incase you think something is wrong with my image link, the one I am using is otherwise working perfectly, it just has more coordinates and other goodies. I took one of them and replaced it with `{{building.mapcoords}}`.

Here is where `building.mapcoords` is coming from:

```
$scope.building = [{
        name:"name2",
        mapcoords:"80,-170",
        address:"address2",
        htmlcoords:"556,69,565,72,568,75,568,85,564,92,559,100,557,108,554,98,550,92,546,86,546,76,552,69",
    },{
        name:"name1",
        mapcoords:"",
        address:"address1",
        htmlcoords:"699,270,708,274,710,277,710,285,707,291,702,300,699,308,696,300,693,292,689,287,688,276,694,271"
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does it do when it doesn't work? have you inspected your network tab to see the path that is used to request the image? You haven't given us much to work with..

Comment: Also, you should be using ng-src so that you don't send a badrequest to the api before angular gets to parse it.

Comment: @KevinB I added the ng-src. Also, The marker on the map just disappears when I run it. If there is anything more you need to work with, just let me know.

Comment: Open the network tab and look at the image url being requested. Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: @KevinB I don't understand. The only image is the static map image, which yes otherwise appears fine. That marker is otherwise there fine if I use the coordinates. But no I do not see an image in the network tab, just something about ajax/angularjs. At any rate, I am going to assume that you are getting at this is totally possible, which was my question, which then I am going to ask, building.mapcoords is actually an object I think it is called? I'll paste it in my code, so I tried calling it like building[0].mapcoords since there is more than one I don't know if that is correct?

Comment: I ignored the is it possible apparently, usually the answer to that question is yes, in one way or another

Comment: @KevinB yes but I initially wanted to know if it is possible to do it the way I explained, so that I wasn't beating my head against the wall trying to get it to work.

Comment: Building is I fact an array, so, yes, you'll have to use it like an array. building[0].mapcoords

Comment: @KevinB ran out of room in comment/thought it implied, building[0].mapcoords didn't work either, is why I wasn't sure if it was the correct way.

Comment: well, it is the correct way, so... problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Though, in your data, the mapcoords are blank... is that intended?

Comment: @ KevinB Yea at the time that I pasted it in it was blank cuz I keep going back and forth since I am otherwise doing other stuff with the code/data. Where else could the problem lie? I mean, the code otherwise is functioning perfectly, it is only when I swap out the coords with the {{building.mapcoords}} does that specific marker disappear. And, actually, since this may be what you were looking before when asking about network tab, when I inspect element, the img src url is, where the coords are suppose to be it is '||90,-180'. Between the pipes being blank where coords should be

Comment: Try removing the img tag and just outputting the result of `{{building[0].mapcoords}}` directly on the page. Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: @KevinB Know what it looks like that worked afterall. I probably was testing without everything being quite right. I swear I tried that multiple times yesterday when I first posted this! Thank you though for taking the time to help me through working this out! Sometimes it takes another to work through brain stumps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`ngSrc`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) Should work fine, because you make another request to the url, think of it as just a resource, a different image